# One-liner for creating struct with blank fields?

Tags: go

I have a struct with blank fields:

```
type Foo struct {
    a uint32
    b uint32
    c uint32
    _ uint32 //padding
}
```

For structs without blank fields I enjoy using one-liner initialization. But, I cannot seem to do this for types *with* blank fields:

```
Foo{1,2,3}   // too few values in struct initializer
Foo{1,2,3,0} // cannot refer to blank field or method
Foo{1,2,3,_} // cannot use _ as value
```

To keep the nice syntax, must I name the unused field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the fields

```
f := Foo{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
fmt.Println(f) //{1 2 3 0}
```